# STL remove first element that matches a predicate from a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, predicate

What is an efficient way to erase the first element in a vector that matches a predicate? I am storing unique values in a vector so I wouldn't want the algorithm to search the whole container.

Currently I am doing:

```
if ((auto it = std::find_if(container.begin(),container.end(),
    [](Type& elem){ return elem == value;}) != container.end()))
{
        container.erase(it);
}
```

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: That looks fine, but make the lambda take a `const` reference. Do you have any problem with this approach?

Comment: Better use `std::set` if you want to maintain uniqueness?

Comment: @Nawaz Or keep the vector sorted, and use `std::lower_bound`.  There are several different solutions, each appropriate for difference cases.

Comment: @Nawaz I need a sequential container for caching purposes. Erasing happens rarely.

Comment: @Veritas: Hmmm, then use `std::vector` and to search, use `std::lower_bound` as it is faster (logarithmic) compared to `std::find_if` (which is linear).

Comment: @Nawaz Assuming the type has an ordering of course. :-) @Veritas Depending on the size of container, `std::find_if` or `std::lower_bound` will be faster. So I would recommend quick bench against expected sizes. (oh and `std::find_if` does abort search on first match, so you won't run through the whole vector)

Comment: @Xarn But std::lower_bound` requires sorting, so it also depends on how many searches you want to make.

Comment: there is also `std::remove_if`, or even `std::remove` if you want to delete by value. It depends on what you understand by "efficient". IF it is only done rarely, you actually don't have to care about efficiency

Comment: @juanchopanza True enough, but only once. And since deletion is rare I assumed that insertion (or modification in general) is also rare. Then the question is whether less cache-friendly access pattern with O(log N) is better enough than cache-friendly O(N) access pattern with expected collection size. (If the elements are unorderable or the order inside vector doesn't matter, as MatthiasB pointed out, `std::remove*` is strictly better as it finds the element in linear time and allows us to remove it in constant time, unlike `std::find_if` + `vector.erase`)

Comment: @MatthiasB: `std::remove*` does NOT remove the elements from the container. It only shifts the elements. You need to use erase along with remove!

Comment: @Nawaz thanks for adding. I thought it should be clear by reading the reference of the commands, but it's always better to mention it.

Comment: your predicate could also be replaced by `std::equal_to<T>()`, which does exactly what your lambda expression does. But I have to admit that lambda look very bad-ass :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a minor improvement:

```
container.erase(
  std::remove(container.begin(), container.end(), value),
  container.end()
);
```

of if you want to use an unary predicate `my_predicate`:

```
container.erase(
  std::remove_if(container.begin(), container.end(), my_predicate),
  container.end()
);
```

This has exactly the same performance characteristics (find+erase together will touch all elements as well), but elegantly avoids special cases (`!= container.end()`) because it is ranged based.

If you don't care about keeping the vector stable (or sorted!) you can also `swap` the found element to the `back()` and `pop_back()` which will slightly improve the average (but not asymptotic!) runtime.

Not to forget this is also a commonly accepted C++ idiom, so it can be more easily recognized.

Comment: The question here says "remove first element that matches" and "wouldn't want the algorithm to search the whole container".  These suggestions remove all matching elements, and search the whole container. The swap suggestion is a good one, though.

Comment: The question also says that elements are unique, so it really is the same.